# Plotting a dictionary with multiple values per key

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
1: ['4026', '4024', '1940', '2912', '2916], 2: ['3139', '2464'], 3:['212']...
```

For a few hundred keys, I'd like to plot them with the key as y for its set of x values, I tried this bit of code which gives the error underneath:

```
for rank, structs in b.iteritems():
    y = b.keys()
    x = b.values()
    ax.plot(x, y, 'ro')
    plt.show()

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

I'm at a bit of a loss on how to proceed so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to construct your list of Xs and Ys manually:

```
In [258]: b={1: ['4026', '4024', '1940', '2912', '2916'], 2: ['3139', '2464'], 3:['212']}

In [259]: xs, ys=zip(*((int(x), k) for k in b for x in b[k]))

In [260]: xs, ys
Out[260]: ((4026, 4024, 1940, 2912, 2916, 3139, 2464, 212), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3))

In [261]: plt.plot(xs, ys, 'ro')
     ...: plt.show()
```

resulting:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

#### 1) Repeat your x values

`plot` expects a list of x values and a list of y values which have to have the same length. That's why you have to repeat the `rank` value several times. `itertools.repeat()` can do that for you.

#### 2) change your iterator

`iteritems()` already returns a tuple `(key,value)`. You don't have to use `keys()` and `items()`.

Here's the code:

```
import itertools
for rank, structs in b.iteritems():
    x = list(itertools.repeat(rank, len(structs)))
    plt.plot(x,structs,'ro')
```

#### 3) combine the plots

Using your code, you'd produce one plot per item in the dictionary. I guess you rather want to plot them within a single graph. If so, change your code accrodingly:

```
import itertools
x = []
y = []
for rank, structs in b.iteritems():
    x.extend(list(itertools.repeat(rank, len(structs))))
    y.extend(structs)
plt.plot(x,y,'ro')
```

#### 4) example

Here's an example using your data:

```
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
d = {1: ['4026', '4024', '1940', '2912', '2916'], 2: ['3139', '2464'], 3:['212']}
x= []
y= []
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    x.extend(list(itertools.repeat(k, len(v))))
    y.extend(v)
plt.xlim(0,5)
plt.plot(x,y,'ro')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is because you mismatched your data entries.

Currently you have

```
1: ['4026', '4024', '1940', '2912', '2916']
2: ['3139', '2464'],
...
```

hence

```
x = [1,2,...]
y = [['4026', '4024', '1940', '2912', '2916'],['3139', '2464'],...
```

when you really need

```
x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, ...]
y = ['4026', '4024', '1940', '2912', '2916', '3139', '2464',...]
```

Try

```
for rank, structs in b.iteritems():
    # This matches each value for a given key with the appropriate # of copies of the 
    # value and flattens the list
    # Produces x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, ...]
    x = [key for (key,values) in b.items() for _ in xrange(len(values))]

    # Flatten keys list
    # Produces y = ['4026', '4024', '1940', '2912', '2916, '3139', '2464',...]
    y = [val for subl in b.values() for val in subl]

    ax.plot(x, y, 'ro')
    plt.show()
```